# How to display the SimpleClassName at each level of the inheritance hierarchy using a method that is inherited?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I want to create a method `printKlass()` in my top-level class which is inherited and prints a top-level variable `KLASS` containing the value of `getClass().getSimpleName()`.

So, in the case of class A, the `printKlass` method should write `A`.

And class B should print `B`.

But the compiler won't let me access the `getClass` method in the part class - it says `this` is not available in a `static` context.

How do I get around this?

```
public class A 
{
    protected static final String KLASS = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); // "Cannot use 'this' in a static context

    protected
    public void printKlass()
    {
        System.out.println(KLASS);
    }
}

public class B extends A
{

    //...

    printKlass(); // Should say "B", not "A"

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a *static* field, it cannot have different values for different classes.

What's wrong with ?

```
public void printKlass()
{
    return System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```